# How best to tag questions characterized by not planning ahead?

Tags: discussion, tagging

When asking a question about cheapest way to do something good answers will often advise you too book stuff in advance.

This is great but quite often these are not the answers you're looking for for various reasons.

- You want to travel without a plan (like me) and just go where you please as things unfold.
- Something came up and you have to travel soon and you didn't foresee it in advance.

Because of this it's handy to be able to tag a question (as well as word it) to rule out in advance answers what might seem like obvious and unhelpful under the circumstances of the information you're looking for.

You might compare this to our tag for advice about travel modes excluding flying: [overland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overland).

So what's a good wording for a tag in a similar vein for advice about travel excluding booking in advance?

So far we've thought of these (me plus whoever was on chat) but none seem to be perfect:

- last-minute
- no-plans
- unplanned
- roaming
- no-advance-plans

Does anyone think one of these is perfect after all, or have another suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

[no-advance-plans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-advance-plans), while wordy, is the most unambiguous. 'Unplanned' doesn't necessarily have to be last minute, and 'last minute' itself can mean something else altogether (a la "I'm making plans last minute and I'm willing to pay *anything* for flights / accommodation.") 'Roaming' can be confused with mobile phone terminology.

Comment: Cool I'll use this now and if somebody offers up something better we can use our advanced tag synonym skillz!

Answer (score 2):

impulsive? spontaneous? short-notice?

Comment: I think "impulsive" and "spontaneous" get the right idea but "short notice" misses the wandering reason for not planning.

Answer (score 2):

IMO tag should not exist at all. There are five Open Qs to which it is applied and really only one of these is about 'no advance planning'. The tag does have one follower but as a means to collect like items together it seems pretty useless. Seeking to buy Disney tickets at short-notice has very little in common with seeking to buy ferry or air tickets at short notice, or to hire a car at short notice or to get in to a show without buying a ticket in advance.

Comment: Yes the site was young and new six years ago. I guess such a tag wasn't a great idea after all. I don't know whether a "short notice" tag instead might still be a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

Urgent?

Actually, I like [short-notice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-notice) as an option...or even [lastminute](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lastminute).

Comment: "Urgent" really misses the wandering without plans angle, the other two are better.

Comment: Urgent. Plz send the travel plans.